# progress bar turning slow

Tags: android, progress

> ```
> <ProgressBar
>     android:id="@+id/progress"
>     android:layout_width="200dp"
>     android:layout_height="200dp"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>     android:indeterminate="false"
>     android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
>     android:max="100" />
>
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:pivotX="50%"
> android:pivotY="50%"
> <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="4"
>   android:thicknessRatio="48" android:useLevel="false">
>   <size android:width="45dip" android:height="45dip" /> 
>   <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
>     android:startColor="#52c1b1" android:centerColor="#52c1b1"
>     android:endColor="#ffffff" android:centerY="0.50" />
> </shape>
>  </animated-rotate>
> ```

its running slow, like  moving as if something slowing it down... 
It works normal and quick on kit kat, but other versions it runs slow

Comment: progress bar runs on UI thread. If you are doing another operation at UI thread it may cause a "slow running" on device. 4.4 devices have more efficient memory and cpu, so you may see progress bar is running faster. To sum up, you should better check your operations while progress bar is showing.

Comment: I do aysnctask and call the server, when data returns from server i go to main thread to display data.

Comment: do note with default progress bar it works normal quick.

Comment: here is how i call my asynctask to perform abds get things from server NetworkService networkCall = new NetworkService(url);
   networkCall.delegate = this;
   networkCall.execute();

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea or another comment with this info you gave. I hope someone helps you.